# How do I write an SVG string to file in C#

Tags: c#, svg

I have an SVG string that I want to save as an svg file to a server with C#. I am using the following code:

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
Directory.CreateDirectory(AppSettings.ExportFolderPath.TrimEnd('\\') + String.Format("\\{0}\\svg", guid));
var svgFile = Path.Combine(AppSettings.ExportFolderPath.TrimEnd('\\') + String.Format("\\{0}\\svg\\graph.svg", guid));

File.WriteAllText(svgFile, svg);
```

On the last line I write the svg string to the file but when I open the generated file it is not SVG and seems to be garbage text.

EX:

[image]

The SVG that I have should be formatted correctly since it comes directly from the browser (and displays correctly before I send it to C#). Here is a snippet of the generated SVG:

[image]

Edit:

Here is an image of the svg variable at the time of the File.WriteAllText call.

[image]

Edit 2:
[JSBIN for the svg](http://jsbin.com/raqelah/edit?html,js,output) The svg in the JSBin is the exact same as the svg variable. Upon inspection of the output svg file, it did indeed get written to the file. For some reason it will not open correctly. This is not a C# writeAllText issue like I believed.

Comment: No part of your code has anything to do with the file content.

Comment: Please add a screenshot of how the `svg` variable looks in the debugger on the line `File.WriteAllText(svgFile, svg);`?

Comment: Have you examined the contents of your `svg` variable to determine if it actually contains the data you expect?

Comment: Please would you post text instead of images of text.

Comment: @SLaks Do you mean the generated svg file? The svg variable contains the svg content that gets written to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SVG string did get written to the output file correctly. When opening the file with inkscape it looked as expected (opening in the browser did not work initially).

Thanks for the suggestions!